# SFML with apple silicon m1

Tags: sfml, apple-m1

I have MacBook Air with m1 chip and tried to install SFML according to the instructions on the official website however I can not compile the project for example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCOn8.jpg)

EDIT: I moved the Xcode app act via rosetta 2 and now it works I would love to know if there is a solution that will activate it natively

Comment: Please do not paste images of errors. Pasting errors as text will help others find the error using a web search engine or this site's search engine. Use markdown formatting with triple backquotes to format the error output so it's formatted nicely and doesn't take too much space on the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are receiving is telling you that the version being linked is for MacOS on x32_64, while trying to compile for arm64. This is incompatible, given they're two different platforms.

Are you compiling SFML from source? It doesn't look like SFML has precompiled binaries for MacOS-arm64, but the source code does have arm compatibility. Compiling from source would be operating system agnostic as long as everything is there (and supports arm64.) SFML has an article on how to compile from source with CMake: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php

While I can't guarantee this will fix your issue, it's definitely worth a try if you haven't yet.

The reason using Rosetta made this work is because Rosetta emulates some parts of x32_64. Running these apps in Rosetta would essentially be the same as compiling your project on an Intel based Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if it can help some, just make your pc believe that you have an intel chip, by adding `/usr/bin/arch -x86_64` before your order.

example:

```
/usr/bin/arch -x86_64 clang main.c -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-system
```

Comment: I feel this is a bad practice to do so. It may change how the computer behaves in the long run. How would you turn your laptop back to the original state?

Comment: @ZeidTisnes This command does not permanently change anything on your computer. It just temporarily executes a command with a different BIN file.